# How to overcome clock stretching on I2C

Tags: i2c, clock

I have the clock stretching issue on my I2C line, attached is the below snapshot of it..

[image]

I have a Kinetis K64 board communicating to a MAX7304 port expander at 400 Khz.

Should I get the driver having the workaround, should the pull up resistor need to be changed or should I play around with capacitance? I need a hint why I am actually getting this clock stretching.

With all the reading, I have understood why it happens. I am trying to understand how to tackle it.

Any thought highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: You get clock stretching when the I2C slave asks for it. Changing resistors or capacitors won't help, you need to adapt the I2C master to deal with it (which might mean a workaround in the driver).

Comment: @BrianDrummond the master might be clock stretching as well when the software is written to be slow. The [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7304.pdf) of the MAX7304 doesn't mention clock stretching or special timings for writing, so I'd look in the I²C driver to improve performance, maybe use DMA.

Comment: @Arsenal, if the master does it, it's not "clock stretching", it's just a longer clock period.

Comment: @user2054364, which part of your timing diagram are you calling "clock stretching"?

Comment: @ThePhoton on a scope it would look the same though? You could place series resistors to find out which one is pulling it low, but in this case I highly suspect it's the master.

Comment: That's not an oscilloscope, it's a Seele logic analyzer. In reality the rising edge has to be more like an RC charging waveform, and a key part of optimizing an I2C system is looking at that rising edge to see if its rise time is fast enough. The logic analyzer isn't showing that information, it's only showing a digital low or high logic level.

Answer (score 6):

The MAX7304 is not capable of clock stretching, so the issue lies with your I²C driver in your software.

Relevant [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7304.pdf#page=12) quote:

> **The device’s SCL line operates only as an input.** A pullup resistor is required on SCL if there are
>   multiple masters on the 2-wire interface, or if the master
>   in a single-master system has an open-drain SCL output.

(emphasis mine)

So it cannot pull the SCL line low. Your microcontroller peripheral is doing that because it doesn't get filled with data fast enough.

---

My preferred approach to get transmission times shorter, is to use DMA, which in most cases gives optimal throughput.

If DMA is not an option and you are using an interrupt driven approach, make sure that the next data to be transmitted is readily available and your interrupt is very quick to put the next data byte in the register.

Answer (score 3):

Go read the IIC spec.  Clock stretching is a slave's way to slow down the bus to the speed it can handle.  It is not a function of resistors and capacitors.  The pullup resistors need to be what they need to be to pull up the line, but not require more than the maximum current for the line to be low.  As for capacitors, don't put capacitors on either IIC line.

Clock stretching is not a problem to solve.  It is the system working correctly to allow the slave to function as intended.  There is nothing to fix here.  You shouldn't be in here at this level without understanding IIC anyway.

Comment: agree with everything except the last sentence.